# Not able to generate proper XSD for an XML,contains Map with Key,value structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

Below is the XML.I tried with online conversion but not getting proper one.
Here for Key "**Address**",all fields getting generated perfectly but for other three, it is not even generating the entry.

```
<map>
<entry key="address" id="1345365ugj57656">
    <addressline1>addressline1</addressline1>
    <addressline2>addressline2</addressline2>
</entry>
<entry key="userCode">1400004811</entry>
<entry key="coupons"/>
<entry key="assistagent">
    <null/>
</entry>
</map>
```

Getting below generated XSD.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="map">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="addressline1" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="addressline2" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="optional"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: I am trying to map "usercode" value to another XML. Is there any solution through XSLT ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve something that should not be done in this way. Basically you are forcing to be the same element (key) used in the same namespace (blank) in a different way which is not correctly designed. Either use a different namespace for each "key" or use the compilation of all possible type of keys and mark every element optional or do some inheritance eg. key of xsi:type "xxx" and other key of xsi:type "yyy" - this is propably the way you want to go...